fedora core ignition config partition errors
trying to boot fedora core using PXE.  my butane config is...
variant: fcos
version: 1.4.0
storage:
  disks:
    - device: /dev/disk/by-id/coreos-boot-disk
      wipe_table: true
      partitions:
      - number: 1
        label: boot
        size_mib: 1024
      - number: 4
        label: root
        size_mib: 16384
      - label: docker
        number: 5
        size_mib: 163840
      - label: data
        number: 6
        size_mib: 0
  filesystems:
    - path: /boot
      label: boot
      device: /dev/disk/by-partlabel/boot
      format: ext4
      wipe_filesystem: true
      with_mount_unit: true
    - device: /dev/disk/by-partlabel/root
      path: /
      format: xfs
      label: root
      wipe_filesystem: true
      with_mount_unit: true
    - path: /var/lib/docker
      label: docker
      device: /dev/disk/by-partlabel/docker
      format: xfs
      wipe_filesystem: false
      with_mount_unit: true

This is throwing an error error at $.storage.disks.0.partitions.5: cannot use the same partition label twice.  i'm guessing i've got a partition number incorrect somewhere, but i can't seem to find the docs with the magic.  anybody got the secret sauce here?
